# What if my question was not well defined and I got two types of answers?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

My question [How to divide natural number N into M nearly equal summands?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081079/how-to-divide-natural-number-n-into-m-nearly-equal-summands) was not well defined from the math point of view.

Ergo I got both answers, answering my exact question and answers, answering question which was in my mind, but not formulated well.

If it would programmers site I would definitely award answer saying what I wanted to get.

But in mathematics this can be incorrect.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If multiple answers helped you, definitely vote both upward, and give the check to the one that helped the most

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description, my understanding is that:

1. You asked a question that was ambiguously stated (where different interpretations could result in different answers), or possibly incorrectly stated (where you *meant* to ask X, but really asked Y.)
2. You have some answers that respond to your question *exactly as stated* and some that respond to the question you had in your mind.
3. You are conflicted over which answer to accept--the one that answers the question you asked, versus the one that answers the question you wanted answered. `:)`

As always, the recommendation is **accept the answer that was most helpful to you**.  If this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201314) (which I think it is), that's OK--my suggestion stays the same.

Comment: But if the other answer was also helpful, leave a comment on it saying so. And vote it up.